Typing return of `__getattr__` method
Earlier today I fell victim to the XY problem where I was trying to get help with an approach to my problem that turned out to be futile, and the best solution to my problem was much simpler and was only uncovered once I shared the real problem I was solving. However, it has been bothering me that I wasn't able to figure out my original approach. It seems very possible, yet neither I nor the couple of people helping me were about to figure it out. Even though my true problem was solved, I would like to figure this out.
My original approach to my problem had a class wrapping another class, using __getattr__ to pass any attribute queries that aren't in the wrapper class to the wrapped class.
#generic_example.py

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.restaurant: str = "taco bell"
        self.finger_count: int = 10
        self.login_info: dict[str, str] = {
            "username": "SilentHare",
            "password": "123passw0rd",
        }

    def foo_method(self) -> None:
        print("This method is also an attribute")
        print(f"Login info is {self.login_info}")


class FooWrapper:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo_instance: Foo = Foo()

    def __getattr__(self, attr: str):
        if hasattr(self.foo_instance, attr):
            return getattr(self.foo_instance, attr)

        raise AttributeError

The issue I was unable to solve was how to properly type the return of the __getattr__ method.
An object return type is technically correct since no matter what gets returned, it will always be an object, but that is not helpful at all, and in fact your type checker will always yell are you whenever you try to use a method of the attribute you fetch since not all objects will have that method. I'm not sure whether an Any return type would be considered technically correct or not, since Any implies that the return can be anything and that there is no relationship between the argument and the return. Needless to say, it is also not what I am looking for.
Obviously there is a relationship between the attr arg and the return type, so there must be some way to express it, right? The functions return type is the same type as the foo_instance's attr. If the relationship was between the type of the attr arg and the return type, that would be trivial to express with a typevar. But instead the relationship is between the value of the attr arg and the return type. I have no clue how to express this relationship.
I believe there is a way using literals and overloads, but it is not feasible to manually implement the overloads with literals for all of the different attributes and types, especially if the wrapped class is under development and is expected to change. I feel like there must be a better way.
Is it possible to express the type using typevars? Is it even possible? I don't know much about them, but isn't there a way to extend python's type system with mypy plugins. Is that necessary?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

"... since Any implies that the return can be anything and that there is no relationship between the argument and the return." I don't think Any implies no relationship between argument and return, it just implies no relationship between argument type (always str) and return type (can be anything). So, Any looks like a good choice to me.

Also, you don't have to put type hints on everything

Related, if not duplicates: How to type-hint return type of __getattr__ method?, Python proxy class with type hints.

@Aemyl While Any is correct I guess, typing a return as Any doesn’t help with type checking or type-specific autocompletion. Also, I like to type  everything to make it harder for me to make mistakes. Though I normally don’t type hint literals like I did in the example.

@InSync The second one is a different problem, the first one is kinda a dupe, but the answer is not really doesn’t seem feasible unless the wrapped class is relatively small and you know it will not change anymore. It seems like there has to be a better way.

@Aemyl no, Any basicaly means "don't type check this". You might as well just use # type: ignore

One solution for this might be a combination of typing.overload with typing.Literal like this:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Literal, overload

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.restaurant: str = "taco bell"
        self.finger_count: int = 10
        self.login_info: dict[str, str] = {
            "username": "SilentHare",
            "password": "123passw0rd",
        }

    def foo_method(self) -> None:
        print("This method is also an attribute")
        print(f"Login info is {self.login_info}")


class FooWrapper:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo_instance: Foo = Foo()

    @overload
    def __getattr__(self, attr: Literal["restaurant"]) -> str:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getattr__(self, attr: Literal["finger_count"]) -> int:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getattr__(self, attr: Literal["login_info"]) -> dict[str, str]:
        ...

    @overload
    def __getattr__(self, attr: Literal["foo_method"]) -> Callable[[], None]:
        ...

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # actual implementation
        return getattr(self.foo_instance, attr)

This comes with the drawback that if you want to change the interface of Foo, you have to change these overloads as well.

LiteralString doesn't accept any arguments. You probably mean Literal?

@InSync You're correct, thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer.
